# How do I selectively update columns in a table when using LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to load data from a text file into a MySQL table, by calling MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE from a Java process. This file can contain some data for the current date and also for previous days. The table can also contain data for previous dates. The problem is that some of the columns in the file for previous dates might have changed. But I don't want to update all of these columns but only want the latest values for some of the columns.

Example,

Table

```
+----+-------------+------+------+------+
| id | report_date | val1 | val2 | val3 |
+----+-------------+------+------+------+  
|  1 | 2012-12-01  |   10 |    1 |    1 |  
|  2 | 2012-12-02  |   20 |    2 |    2 |
|  3 | 2012-12-03  |   30 |    3 |    3 |
+----+-------------+------+------+------+
```

Data in Input file:

```
1|2012-12-01|10|1|1
2|2012-12-02|40|4|4
3|2012-12-03|40|4|4
4|2012-12-04|40|4|4
5|2012-12-05|50|5|5
```

Table after the load should look like

```
mysql> select * from load_infile_tests;
+----+-------------+------+------+------+
| id | report_date | val1 | val2 | val3 |
+----+-------------+------+------+------+
|  1 | 2012-12-01  |   10 |    1 |    1 |
|  2 | 2012-12-02  |   40 |    4 |    2 |
|  3 | 2012-12-03  |   40 |    4 |    3 |
|  4 | 2012-12-04  |   40 |    4 |    4 |
|  5 | 2012-12-05  |   50 |    5 |    5 |
+----+-------------+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that column val3 values are not updated. Also I need to do this for large files as well, some files can be >300Megs or more, and so it needs to be a scalable solution.

Thanks,
Anirudha

Comment: So you dont want to update column named as val3? Just want to make sure.

Comment: yeah, i dont want to update some columns, like val3 in this example.

Comment: If you don't want to update that column then it will set to null. Do you want that?

Comment: no i dunt want to set columns to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to use LOAD DATA INFILE with REPLACE option, but in this case records will be dropped and added again, so old `val3` values will be lost.

Try to load data into temporary table, then update your table from temp. table using [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)/[UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) or [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statements.

Comment: that is something that we tried but doing some benchmarks the time it takes to do the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is approx 50% greater than the time for the LOAD DATA INFILE. Was hoping if there is another solution that doesn't take as much time.

Comment: It seems there is no other way to do it faster. But, try to write an application that would read CSV file and generate SQL statements.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem like there is a clean way to do this with SQL. Apparently this is what Hadoop is for. :)